# When a custom form is displayed in a custom template, ajax does not work

Tags: forms, ajax, 9

**What I want to do**

I want to display a custom form with a custom template and use ajax in it to change values in the form.

**Problem**

Custom template notation prevents ajax from working.
I didn't change anything in php, just twig, and tried 2 patterns as shown below.
In twig1, when I changed the value of "a", the value of "b" became "hogehoge" and the log was output.
However, in twig2, the value of b was not changed even if the value of a was changed, and there was no "update" in the log.
!!Both of the name of templates are "sampleexample.html.twig", and both of them are rendered.

SampleForm2.php

```
    <?php

namespace Drupal\sampleexample\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand;

class SampleForm2 extends FormBase {

  /**
   * Current user account.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface
   */
  protected $currentUser;

  /**
   * Node storage.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\node\NodeStorageInterface
   */
  protected $nodeManager;
  protected $taxonomanager;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(
    EntityTypeManager $entity_type_manager,
    AccountProxyInterface $current_user
  ) {
    $this->currentUser = $current_user;
    $this->nodeManager = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('node');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('entity_type.manager'),
      $container->get('current_user')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId(){
    return 'sampleform2';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) { 
    $form['#theme'] = 'sampleexample';
    $form['a'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#size' => '60',
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::myAjaxCallback', // don't forget :: when calling a class method.
        'disable-refocus' => FALSE, // Or TRUE to prevent re-focusing on the triggering element.
        'event' => 'change',
        'progress' => [
          'type' => 'throbber',
          'message' => $this->t('Verifying entry...'),
        ],
      ]
    ];
    $form['b'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#size' => '60',
    ];
    $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Save data'),
    ];


    return $form;
  }

  function myAjaxCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, Request $request) {
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse $response */
    $response = new AjaxResponse(); 
    
    \Drupal::logger('b')->notice('update');
    $form['b']['#value'] = $this->t('hogehoge');
    $response
        ->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand(".form-item--b", $form['b']));
    return $response;

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    
  }
}
```

twig1

```
{{ form_build_id }}
{{ form_token }}
{{ form_id }}

{{ form }}
```

twig2

```
{{ form_build_id }}
{{ form_token }}
{{ form_id }}

{{ form.a }}
{{ form.b }}
{{ form.actions.submit }}
```

**Points of concern**
I checked if there is any difference in the dom displayed on the page when using twig1 and twig2 respectively. I found that

```
<input autocomplete="off" data-drupal-selector="form-if-9dbyv7ohy9odmuog4qlckk6aemou8w5bnljfhobi"
             type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-If-9Dbyv7ohY9oDmUOG4qLCkk6AemOu8w5bnlJFHObI">
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-sampleform2-form-token" type="hidden" name="form_token"
            value="gjDpTprqywwq9hMaizsiaL6YU300vcJJ36FRW_o2sFM">
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-sampleform2" type="hidden" name="form_id" value="sampleform2">
```

And the callback is written differently.

twig1

```
"ajax":{"edit-a":{"callback":"::myAjaxCallback","disable-refocus":false,"event":"change","progress":{"type":"throbber","message":"Verifying entry..."},
```

twig2

```
"ajax":{"edit-a":{"callback":"Drupal\\sampleexample\\Form\\SampleForm2::myAjaxCallback","disable-refocus":false,"event":"change","progress":{"type":"throbber","message":"Verifying entry..."},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only variable available in a #theme form template is

```
{{ form }}
```

and this is the only thing you need to render. If you render single form elements or groups then include the rest of the `form` variable with the help of the `|without` filter.

A more complex example from the core Claro theme:

*core/themes/claro/templates/node-edit-form.html.twig*

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for a node edit form.
 *
 * Two column template for the node add/edit form.
 *
 * This template will be used when a node edit form specifies 'node_edit_form'
 * as its #theme callback.  Otherwise, by default, node add/edit forms will be
 * themed by form.html.twig.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - form: The node add/edit form.
 *
 * @see claro_form_node_form_alter()
 */
#}
<div class="layout-node-form clearfix">
  <div class="layout-region layout-region--node-main">
    <div class="layout-region__content">
      {{ form|without('advanced', 'footer', 'actions') }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="layout-region layout-region--node-secondary">
    <div class="layout-region__content">
      {{ form.advanced }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="layout-region layout-region--node-footer">
    <div class="layout-region__content">
      <div class="divider"></div>
      {{ form.footer }}
      {{ form.actions }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't render the entire form variable then libraries like Ajax don't work.

Comment: You are Perfect! It did exactly what I expected it to do.

Comment: I did the method you wrote and it added form_build_id, form_token and form_id. However, I originally included them in the template.
Is it unnecessary to include the following in the template?

{{ form_build_id }}
{{ form_token }}
{{ form_id }}

Comment: This is unnecessary, in this kind of template. You have probably seen this in attempts to hack the form wrapper `form.html.twig`, a different template rendering the outside of the HTML form tag. They then try to render the already rendered inside of the form again, which only works for simple forms.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
Thank you very much. I got it.